# Links blog post in Orchard CMS?

Tags: orchardcms

I have a list of blog posts in **Orchard CMS**. This is my code:

```
@{
    IEnumerable<object>
    blogPosts = Model.ContentItems;
    Model.ContentItems.Classes.Add("content-items");
    Model.ContentItems.Classes.Add("blog-posts");
}

<div class="row">
    @foreach (var item in blogPosts)
    {
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
            <div>
                <div class="blog-seg post-item seg">
                    <div>@Display(item)</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

I want each `DIV` to have a link to the post. How can I do this?

Comment: use `@Html.ItemDisplayLink(item)`

Comment: I have this error: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<dynamic>' does not contain a definition for 'ItemDisplayLink' and the best extension method overload 'Orchard.Mvc.Html.ContentItemExtensions.ItemDisplayLink(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, Orchard.ContentManagement.IContent)' has some invalid arguments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following to display links for content items:

```html
@using Orchard.ContentManagement;

@{
    IEnumerable<dynamic>
        blogPosts = Model.ContentItems.ContentItems;
    Model.ContentItems.Classes.Add("content-items");
    Model.ContentItems.Classes.Add("blog-posts");
}

<div class="row">
    @foreach (var item in blogPosts) {
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
            <div>
                <div class="blog-seg post-item seg">
                    <div>
                        @Html.ItemDisplayLink(item.ContentItem as IContent)
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Comment: It has an error.'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<dynamic>' does not contain a definition for 'ItemDisplayLink' and the best extension method overload 'Orchard.Mvc.Html.ContentItemExtensions.ItemDisplayLink(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, Orchard.ContentManagement.IContent)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: I have the same error and ContentItem couldn't be found

Comment: I have this error now Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: can you try the last edit and give me your feedback please.

Comment: It's work but it's not the answer of my question.I solve my problem.Thank U ;)

Comment: @balouchi, this helper is used all over the place in orchard. If this doesn't work you should check your references / web.config.
I know that sometimes there are errors like this, you can read more about it [here](https://github.com/OrchardCMS/Orchard/issues/5272).

A quick solution to your problem may be to set `CopyLocal = true` for `Orchard.Framework` and/or `Orchard.Core`

Comment: I'm agree with you @Xceno.

Answer (score 0):

```
@using Orchard.ContentManagement;
@{
IEnumerable<dynamic>
    blogPosts = Model.ContentItems;
Model.ContentItems.Classes.Add("content-items");
Model.ContentItems.Classes.Add("blog-posts");
```

}

```
<div class="row">
@foreach (var item in blogPosts)
{
    IContent contentItem = item.ContentItem;
    var metadata = contentItem.ContentItem.ContentManager.GetItemMetadata(contentItem);
    string alias = metadata.Identity.Get("alias");

    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <div>
            <div class="blog-seg post-item seg">
                <a href="~/@alias" style="display:block;">@Display(item)</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```